# SyntaxError: invalid syntax (when running python code from shell)

Tags: python, string, shell, syntax-error, quotation-marks

In Jupyter Notebook my Code runs fine, but when I run it from shell i get a syntax error at this part of my code:

```
res = f'"x"'+" "+f'"y"'+" "+f'"t"'+" "+f'"id"'+" "+f'"id2"'
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

However I need the String `res` to look like:

```
""x" "y" "t" "id" "id2""
```

I guess that the way i create it is causing the error.

Is there any other way to create a String containing quotation marks?
Or anything to get rid of the syntax error?
Thanks!

Comment: Your expected output is not valid syntax. Did you mean `a= '"x" "y" "t" "id" "id2"'`?

Comment: Looks like left open parentheses in the line(s) before.

Comment: @roganjosh yes i want a to look as you said

Comment: @KlausD. no that is not the problem. The code runs fine in Jupyter notebook. It is just not valid shell syntax i guess, but i don't know how to get the same String with shell commands

Comment: What version of Python?

Comment: The code is valid **from Python 3.6** on, even that it shows a lack of understanding how format strings and strings in general work.

Comment: @KlausD. as mentioned it is not a Python problem. In python it works. I get it when running from shell

Comment: Like from the OS shell? Bash or similar? It should work in the Python shell but it will definitely not work on bash.

Comment: I am using bash. Sorry, i should have mentioned that @KlausD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer now:

```
res= "\"x\" \"y\" \"t\" \"id\" \"id2\""
```

works for Shell as well as Python

Answer (score 1):

f-strings, or [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) is supported only from python 3.6. If you are using old version of python, try to upgrade. If you have both python2 and python3 installed, make sure you are launching python3

But for the output you expect, you dont need f-strings

```
res = '"x" "y" "t" "id" "id2"'
```